# Buy Now button return url: Update field in database

Tags: php, mysql, paypal

What I'm trying to do (and don't understand how to do it) is after someone completes a successful transaction on PayPal, I need it to go back to my website and update one field in the database relative to the user.

I have no clue on how to do this, and I've been searching around for hours.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this one of two ways.  You could use IPN or PDT to update your database once a payment completes.  The better of the two ways, would be to use IPN, or atleast use IPN in conjunction with PDT.

Instant Payment Notification (IPN) is a message service that notifies you of events related to PayPal transactions. You can use it to automate back-office and administrative functions, such as fulfilling orders, tracking customers, and providing status and other information related to a transaction.

You can find more on IPN the page [here](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro).  Also on that page, off to the left hand side are some more links that are useful as well.  There are pages for creating a listener, setup, testing, IPN history, IPN with FMF, IPN/PDT variables, and sample code [here](https://www.x.com/developers/PayPal/documentation-tools/code-sample/216623).

PayPal’s PDT system sends order confirmations to merchant sites that use PayPal Payments Standard and lets them authenticate this information. Such sites can then display this data locally in an “order confirmation” page.  IPN is more reliable than PDT, and also with PDT it is dependent on the buyer clicking a button to return to your site.  If they they dont click on the button to return to your site, no information is sent back and you can not resend this information like you can with IPN.  You can find more on PDT [here](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/ipn/integration-guide/IPNPDTAnAlternativetoIPN).

I personally only use PDT for crating a dynamic thank you page on my site, and use IPN for updating my database and automating some tasks.  Hope this helps.  :)

Comment: I think I must have done something wrong as I copied the PHP sample code and I get emails from PayPal saying: "Messages sent to the following URL(s) are not being received:

http://clovercloud.net/ipn.php " :/

Comment: Log into your PayPal account that you have this set up on, and check your IPN history.  Go into the details of one of these IPN messages, and see what status code is being returned.  This may help to determine the cause of the issue.  This page may also help you in troubleshooting IPNs.  https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/ipn/pdt/ipn-troubleshooting-tips-0