# how to send and receive back the user_id in the success link of payPal?

Tags: paypal

I'm confused with paypal sequences.
I want to add in the website a donation paypal link "for members only" **it's my client demand** and I want to store in the db if the user have made a donation or not and how much.
Now he is using in the website just the link https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=6SENM6TBA5EPL
so this means that he have an account on paypal and have created a button with this id "6SENM6TBA5EPL". what I know is that from the button config. in paypal site we can set cancel and success links,it's ok.
But I want to send the user_id and receive it back from paypal as a variable on the success link if the donation is made.

So it's just to add another url variable like https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=6SENM6TBA5EPL**&user_id=123**

or I can use the paypal form like this

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="123">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="6SENM6TBA5EPL">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/fr_FR/FR/i/btn/btn_donate_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - la solution de paiement en ligne la plus simple et la plus sécurisée !">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the custom variable as a pass through variable.  Then as far as getting the information back, you can either have it returned through IPN, PDT, or using the rm variable.  I posted more detail on IPN and PDT on this forum posting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15651499/buy-now-button-return-url-update-field-in-database/15658981#15658981).

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="blah blah">
```